# codeigniter form validation callback function with multiple arguments issue: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: forms, codeigniter, undefined, offset, validation

I am receiving multiple errors which are listed below my code.  There was also a mysql error, but I understood that error due to the parts array null values.  I  have no idea why I am receiving those errors.  Can someone explain with a fix also.

line 106: `$this->db->where($parts[1], $value);`

code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('alias','alias_exist','trim|xss_clean|callback_alias_exist_check[livestock.alias]');  

    function alias_exist_check($value, $str)
    {

        $parts = explode('.', $str);    
        $this->db->from($parts[0]);
        $this->db->where($parts[1], $value);
        $result = $this->db->get();

        echo $this->db->last_query();
        //return ($row->count > 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        //echo $table . ' ' . $column;
    }
```

error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: controllers/validate_livestock.php

Line Number: 106

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/dickschi/public_html/lsms/system/libraries/Exceptions.php:166)

Filename: codeigniter/Common.php

Line Number: 356

Thank You,
     Rich

Comment: What's the value of $str, passed into the callback?  It obviously does not have a "." in it.

Comment: What is the purpose of [livestock.alias] ?

Comment: livestock is the table and alias is the column.  those are the values used for the database sql string.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to apply this patch ?

https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/issue/139/validation-callback-parameter-does-not

This is a patch for the file

> /system/libraries/Form_validation.php

which contains the class CI_Form_validation.
In the method `_execute()` line 491, replace the line

```
if (preg_match("/(callback_\w+)/", implode(' ', $rules), $match))
```

by

```
if (preg_match("/(callback_[\[\]\w]+)/", implode(' ', $rules), $match))
```

Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: No, I did not apply that patch.  I am using CI 2.0.  How do I apply this patch?

Comment: Thanks Réjôme for going through the trouble of explaining.  I appreciate the help.  I recently just updated to 2.0 not realizing the issue was with my jquery AJAX DATA.  I set the value to an element that did not exist.  Will this patch fix the "element does not exist" issue?

Comment: I believe it is the main purpose of this patch. Unfortunately, it hasn't been included in the official release yet. If this does fix your problem, please add you comment into the bitbucket ticket ;-)

Comment: I am afraid to change the code :-( I do not want to run into any issues.  I did fix my issue as stated in my previous response.  
  
--Rich

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to pass the column name and table to the function? Cant you just do:

```
function alias_exist_check($value, $str)
{
    $this->db->from('livestock');
    $this->db->where('alias', $value);
    $result = $this->db->get();

    echo $this->db->last_query();
    //return ($row->count > 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    //echo $table . ' ' . $column;
}
```

Comment: I would like the convenience of reusing my code using a function.

Comment: Yes, but would you use a funciton called `alias_exist_check` for anything other than checking wherther an alias exists?

Comment: You are 100% correct.  However, I am moving the sql "stuff" into the modal directory.  I just want the convenience of reusing the code for the future since I am sure I will be checking if something other than alias exists.